Failing to reconnect connector and send messages from MongoDB to Event Hub after initial failure
We connected a MongoDBsource connector from Kafka Connect on Kubernetes to Azure Event Hub. After successfully sending several messages, a message will eventually fail as we test larger message sizes.
When we redeploy our Kafka Connect pod with more resource, or delete and recreate the connector through the Kafka Connect endpoint, no fix is made and we receive the below errors.
Any help would be much appreciated. I've replaced sensitive info in carrot brackets <>.
15:27:05,982 INFO
[cosmosdb-source-develop|task-0] Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description
•   ServerDescription:
o   address: <my_server_address>
o   type: REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY
o   state: CONNECTED
o   ok: true
o   minWireVersion: 0
o   maxWireVersion: 8
o   maxDocumentSize: 16777216
o   logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30
o   roundTripTimeNanos: 86778707
o   setName: '<my_set_name>'
o   canonicalAddress: <my_server_address>
o   hosts: [<my_server_address>]
o   tagSet: TagSet{[Tag{name='region', value='<my_region>’ }]}
o   setVersion: 1
o   lastUpdateTimeNanos: 12352499337633898
(org.mongodb.driver.cluster)
[cluster-ClusterId{value='<my_cluster_id>'}-<my_server_address>]

15:27:05,982 INFO
[cosmosdb-source-develop|task-0] Discovered replica set primary <my_server_address>
(org.mongodb.driver.cluster)
[cluster-ClusterId{value='<my_cluster_id>'}-<my_server_address>]

15:27:05,993 INFO
[cosmosdb-source-develop|task-0] Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:863417751}] to <my_server_address>
(org.mongodb.driver.connection)
[cluster-rtt-ClusterId{value='<my_cluster_id>'}-<my_server_address>]

15:27:06,154 INFO
[cosmosdb-source-develop|task-0] Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:366833602}] to <my_server_address>
(org.mongodb.driver.connection)
[task-thread-cosmosdb-source-develop-0]

15:27:06,168 INFO
[cosmosdb-source-develop|task-0] Watching for collection changes on '<my_db>.<my_collection>'
(com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoSourceTask)
[task-thread-cosmosdb-source-develop-0]

15:27:06,172 INFO
[cosmosdb-source-develop|task-0] Resuming the change stream after the previous offset using resumeAfter:
•   resumeAfter: {"_data": {"$binary": {"base64": "eyJWIjoyLCJSaWQiOiJnd0pQQUxGTGRuUT0iLCJDb250aW51YXRpb24iOlt7IkZlZWRSYW5nZSI6eyJ0eXBlIjoiRWZmZWN0aXZlIFBhcnRpdGlvbiBLZXkgUmFuZ2UiLCJ2YWx1ZSI6eyJtaW4iOiIiLCJtYXgiOiJGRiJ9fSwiU3RhdGUiOnsidHlwZSI6ImNvbnRpbnVhdGlvbiIsInZhbHVlIjoiXCIzMzdcIiJ9fV19", "subType": "00"}}, "_kind": 1}
(com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoSourceTask)
[task-thread-cosmosdb-source-develop-0]

15:27:06,752 INFO
[cosmosdb-source-develop|task-0] Started MongoDB source task
(com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoSourceTask)
[task-thread-cosmosdb-source-develop-0]

15:27:06,752 INFO
[cosmosdb-source-develop|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=cosmosdb-source-develop-0} Source task finished initialization and start
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask)
[task-thread-cosmosdb-source-develop-0]
15:27:12,864 INFO
[cosmosdb-source-develop|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-cosmosdb-source-develop-0] Node 0 disconnected.
(org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[kafka-producer-network-thread | connector-producer-cosmosdb-source-develop-0]

15:27:12,868 INFO
[cosmosdb-source-develop|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-cosmosdb-source-develop-0] Cancelled in-flight PRODUCE request with correlation id 7 due to node 0 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 8ms, elapsed time since send: 8ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
(org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[kafka-producer-network-thread | connector-producer-cosmosdb-source-develop-0]

15:27:12,869 WARN
[cosmosdb-source-develop|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-cosmosdb-source-develop-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 7 on topic-partition develop1.<my_db>.<my_collection>-16, retrying (2147483646 attempts left). Error: NETWORK_EXCEPTION. Error Message: Disconnected from node 0
(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[kafka-producer-network-thread | connector-producer-cosmosdb-source-develop-0]

15:27:12,870 WARN
[cosmosdb-source-develop|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-cosmosdb-source-develop-0] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition develop1.<my_db>.<my_collection>-16 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: Disconnected from node 0. Going to request metadata update now
(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[kafka-producer-network-thread | connector-producer-cosmosdb-source-develop-0]

BELOW ARE PRODUCERCONFIG AND SOURCECONFIG VALUES FROM THE KAFKA CONNECT POD
2024-10-21 15:27:05,277 INFO [cosmosdb-source-develop|task-0] ProducerConfig values:
        acks = -1
        auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
        batch.size = 16384
        bootstrap.servers = <my bootstrap server> 
        buffer.memory = 33554432
        client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
        client.id = connector-producer-cosmosdb-source-develop-0
        compression.type = none
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
        enable.idempotence = true
        enable.metrics.push = true
        interceptor.classes = []
        key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
        linger.ms = 0
        max.block.ms = 9223372036854775807
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1
        max.request.size = 80518918
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partitioner.adaptive.partitioning.enable = true
        partitioner.availability.timeout.ms = 0
        partitioner.class = null
        partitioner.ignore.keys = false
        receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retries = 2147483647
        retry.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.mechanism = PLAIN
        sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
        sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
        sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
        security.protocol = <my_security_protol>
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
        <my_ssl_details> 
        transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
        transactional.id = null
        value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer

INFO SourceConnectorConfig values:

        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        exactly.once.support = requested
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = cosmosdb-source-develop
        offsets.storage.topic = null
        predicates = []
        tasks.max = 1
        topic.creation.groups = []
        transaction.boundary = poll
        transaction.boundary.interval.ms = null
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceConnectorConfig) [DistributedHerder-<info>]
2024-10-21 15:27:05,356 INFO EnrichedConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        exactly.once.support = requested
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = cosmosdb-source-develop
        offsets.storage.topic = null
        predicates = []
        tasks.max = 1
        topic.creation.groups = []
        transaction.boundary = poll
        transaction.boundary.interval.ms = null
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
    ```


It's a network problem, not a resource problem for Connect... You need to get the logs from the broker "node 0" or the leader of develop1.<my_db>.<my_collection>-16
